# Both Wi-fi usb dongle and BT usb dongle stopped working

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, atheros

I'm on Ubuntu 22.10. I don't have cabled internet so I always used my iPhone hotspot to connect to internet.
After installing Ubuntu, my wi-fi dongle (TP Link TL-WN722N) just worked perfectly without any driver. But after IDK what, it stopped working. On Windows 10, when the dongle is plugged, you can see a green light on it. But now on Linux I can't see this light, no matter if i change usb port.
Also the Bluetooth dongle doesn't work. I've never tested it on Linux but in settings i had the ability to turn the bluetooth on.

The only things I've installed are NVIDIA property drivers and VLC.

If I use `lsusb` I can see both dongle

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 2357:0604 TP-Link TP-Link UB500 Adapter
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 258a:1006 Gaming KB Gaming KB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d: C332 Logitech, Inc. G502 Proteus Spectrum Optical Mouse 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID Ocf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The BT dongle is in Bus 005 device 003, the wifi dongle is in Bus 001 device 002.
How can I make them work (without access internet because I don't have cabled internet)?

I tried `sudo modprobe ath9k_htc`
and i got

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath9k_htc not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-31-generic
```

I also tried `sudo dmesg I grep ath` and got

```
    3.234127] systemd[1]: File System Check on Root Device was skipped because of a failed condition check (ConditionPathE xists=!/run/initramfs/fsck-root).
36.563792] audit: type-1107 audit (1676745980.401:52): pid=670 uid=102 autd=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined ms a='addarmor="DENIED" operation="dbus method call" bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/Policykit1/Authority" interface="org „freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAli" mask="send" name=" :1.5" pid-2042 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=
687 peer label="unconfined"
36.564160] audit: type=1107 audit 1676745980.401:53): pid-670 ud=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined ms g= 'apparmor="DENIED" operation-"dbus method call" bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/Policykit1/Authority" interface="org freedesktop.Policykit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=": 1.5" pid-2042 label= "snap.snap-store.snap
-store" peer_pid-687 peer_label="unconfined"
36.5666091 audit: type=1107 audit 1676745980.405:54): pid=670 id=102 aud=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subi=unconfined ms g='apparmor="DENIED" operation-"dbus_method_call" bus-"system" path="/org/freedesktop/Policykiti/Authortty" interface="org [freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask-"send" name-" :1.5" pid-2042 label-"snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=
687 peer_ label="unconfined"
36.566953] audit: type=1107 audit(1676745980.405:55): pid=670 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined ms g= 'apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus method call" bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/Policykit1/Authority" interface="org
•freedesktop.Policykit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask-"send" name=" :1.5" pid-2042 label-"snap. snap-store.snap
ouxsie &
-store" peer pid-687 peer label-"unconfined"
```

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel and check.

Comment: What is the exact response to: `sudo modprobe ath9k_htc` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I've done it but doesn't work. I edited my question with the result of your command. I also added the information about what I've installed.

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel. It looks like the upgrade was not full.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by running Linux with the old kernel. while booting Linux, i chose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and selected the other kernel.

Comment: Now update you system again. It looks like some kernel packages did not install.

Answer (score 1):

Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu, then run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -f
```

That should fix issues with the new kernel.

Answer (score -2):

Install linux-modules-extra package

Comment: Can you add some more details? Step by step guide for novices would be more useful.