# Updated kernel breaks wireless

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

5.19.0-32-generic
Is my new kernel on Ubuntu Jammy on an i5 desktop HP unit. Now the USB wireless dongles won't work. Where can I get a proper driver for these realtek (inexpensive Chinese) wireless devices? I have one with one antenna and two with two antennas. None will work now.

Comment: Check in terminal `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)` If no results see https://askubuntu.com/a/1455564/300665

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb` to the question.